# How to unit test ion-picker with angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I have a `ion-picker` in my component, declared as:

```js
   const picker = await this.pickerController.create({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Seleccionar',
          handler: (selected) => {
            this.setDatesPerWeek(selected.week.value);
          }
        }
      ],
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'week',
          selectedIndex: this.currentWeek - 1,
          options: this.setOptionsPicker()
        }
      ],
      cssClass: 'pickerWeeks'
    });
```

So I have a unit test for the creation and presence of the component `ion-picker`. But the coverage shows that handler of button "Seleccionar" should be tested. In my spec.ts y have:

```js
  it('check picker present', (done) => {
    component.presentPicker();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(pickerSpy.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
```

But IDK, how to test the handler of a button inside ion-picker. I tried to get the button and force the click but I got null in the var of the button. Does anyone have an idea about how to cover this function?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate the click on the picker button by leveraging the jasmine spy API. After the click, you can check the expected outcome.

```js
it('set dates when Seleccionar button of picker clicked', async () => {
   component.presentPicker();
   fixture.detectChanges();
   await fixture.whenStable();
   const buttons = pickerCtrlSpy.create.calls.first().args[0].buttons;
   const selectButton = buttons.find(btn => btn.text === 'Seleccionar');

   await selectButton.handler();

   expect(this.datePerWeek).toEqual(expectedValue)
});
```

Comment: it seems that `pickerSpy.present.calls.first().args` has nothing. Why is this happening?. My spy is declared as `const pickerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Picker', ['present']);`

Comment: And the spy of the controller : 
`const pickerCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('PickerController', ['create']);
pickerCtrlSpy.create.and.callFake(() => pickerSpy);`